# MYSQL not using created index

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a table with a clustered index.

```
Index(region_cd, Activity_mth, HR_rollup, sls_dist_chnl_type_cd) called REGION_CD_3
Index(Activity_mth)
```

When i execute the following query

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT 
  ACTIVITY_MTH,
  SUM(CASE WHEN m2m_ind = 'N' THEN TOT_GA ELSE 0  END) AS GA,
  SUM(CASE WHEN m2m_ind = 'N' THEN TOT_GA_PY ELSE 0 END) 
FROM
  b2b_dashboard_data_dly 
WHERE region_cd = 'PH' 
  AND ACTIVITY_MTH BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-09-30' 
  AND HR_ROLLUP = 'historical' 
  AND SLS_DIST_CHNL_TYPE_CD = 'b2b' 
GROUP BY ACTIVITY_MTH
```

I get the following response for the EXPLAIN.

```
id  | select_type   | table                  | type         | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                           -                 | key                                           | key_len   | ref   | rows  | filtered  | Extra
1   | SIMPLE        | b2b_dashboard_data_dly | index_merge  |REP_HR_EMP_ID,MGR_HR_EMP_ID,AD_HR_EMP_ID,REGION_CD,AREA_CD,ACTIVITY_MTH,HR_ROLLUP,REGION_CD_2,SLS_DIST_CHNL_TYPE_CD,REP_HR_EMP_ID_3,MGR_HR_EMP_ID_3,AD_HR_EMP_ID_3,REGION_CD_3,AREA_CD_3   | REGION_CD_2,HR_ROLLUP,SLS_DIST_CHNL_TYPE_CD   | 93,33,48  | null  | 11480 | 75        | Using intersect(REGION_CD_2,HR_ROLLUP,SLS_DIST_CHNL_TYPE_CD); Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Why if my Index `REGION_CD_3` not being used? How can i optimise this query and my indexing?

Comment: Can you post the structure of the tables involved and some test data? Using [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) would be helpful to help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this query, only the first two columns of that index are useful, because of the range query against the 2nd column of the index.  The values in the last two columns would have to be scanned.

Change the index definition to move the range column to the end:

```
(region_cd, HR_rollup, sls_dist_chnl_type_cd, Activity_mth)
```

Also, change the group by clause to put Activity_mth last and reference all of the other columns in index order.

```
GROUP BY region_cd, HR_rollup, sls_dist_chnl_type_cd, Activity_mth
```

This should give the optimizer an ideal index for the query, and a hint that it can avoid a lot of unnecessary work by reading from this index as opposed to any other.